# Remove menu entries from indicator-applet-complete

Tags: indicator, menu, gnome-classic

I would like to remove shutdown entry from indicator-applet-complete in gnome-classic session in Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a way to achieve that? I don't want to prevent shutdown but just remove entry so users does not blindly click shutdown instead logout.

Answer (score 2):

To answer myself:

Open file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy

Edit two lines: `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>` so you switch yes to no